# Typescript generic with Tuple type

Tags: typescript, generics

What I want is simple: I want to define a tuple type whose second argument is `T[]` if the first argument is determined to be `T`.

I can do this.

```
type TandTArray<T> = [T, T[]]
```

But, i had to specify every T
[image]

But i want it to be determined by the first argument automatically.
I tried this But dosen't work

```
type TandTArray = <T>[T, T[]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a function for generic type to be inferred:

```
const tandTArray = <T>(x: [T, T[]]) => x;

const foo = tandTArray([1, [1]])
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCGYAmAVAggJw-AnjAvDADwoA0AfABQAeAXDANpkwoMC6bAlAeTNQNwBYAFAjQkWADMQIAnESpM2HJQYBGUozUdOIkQHp9MAKLUADgFNgsC1hAZ6KHJZgByaBgCWYAOauYnhAwYCCw8BAQnj5g8ABGADYWcLJQzkmuYACuALaxtq5i4NAwsfAYcgjI6Fi4qhqMrmquOkA)

Comment: Ummm... I would be sad if there is no way to define it without function
But in second thought, I notice that this might impossible.

Comment: Using generic type without generic parameter is only possible with default type parameter, but this won't help here.